# Inequality involving the sin function

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

For every $N \geq 1$ and $1 \leq j \leq N$, $x_{j, N} \in \mathbb{T}$ are chosen such that they satisfy $|x_{j,N} - \frac{j}{N}| \geq \frac{1}{N^{2}}$ and such that $\\\{ x_{j,N} \in \mathbb{T}^{N} \\\}$ is an incommensurate vector. We can then argue (some details omitted here) that for a.e. $x \in \mathbb{T}$, $ \\\{ {(2n+1)(x - x_{j,N})}_{j=1}^{N} \mod \mathbb{Z}^{N} | n \in \mathbb{Z} \\\} $ is dense in $\mathbb{T}^{N}$.

Then, for a.e. $x \in \mathbb{T}$, there are infinitely many choices of $n \geq 1$ such that $ \sin((2n+1)\pi (x - x_{j,N})) \geq \frac{1}{2} $ for $1 \leq j \leq N$.

Hence, for $S_{n}f$ defined as being the convolution of function $f$ with the $n^{th}$ degree Dirichlet Kernel, and $\mu_{N}= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{j=1}^{N} \delta_{ \\\{ x_{j,N} \\\} }$, we have $$|(S_{n}\mu_{N})| \geq \frac{1}{2N} \sum_{j=1}^{N} \frac{1}{|\sin(\pi(x - x_{j,N}))|} \geq C\frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=1}^{N} \frac{1}{(\frac{j}{N})} \geq C \log N$$.

I am unable to prove the penultimate inequality: $\frac{1}{2N} \sum_{j=1}^{N} \frac{1}{|\sin(\pi(x - x_{j,N}))|} \geq C\frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=1}^{N} \frac{1}{(\frac{j}{N})}$.

If one uses the inequality $|\sin(t)|\leq |t|$, then it introduces $\frac{1}{|\sin(\pi(x - x_{j,N}))|} \geq \frac{1}{(\frac{1}{N^{2}})}$ which does not involve $j$.

Any help would be appreciated to understand this inequality.